# Magento tasks for learning

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce, shopping-cart

I am learning Magento. I have already installed and gone through admin side.

Have done for adding customers ,Products ,Pricing or other stuffs. Now I want to learn more things (currently don't want to go for code and database).

Can anyone post here sample tasks (specially for learning). Because as I said am new to magento and don't konow exactly what type of tasks we can do in Magento.

I want some good tricky and sample tasks to do in magento. So I can learn it more.

Answer (score 1):

1.) Change the favicon logo.

2.) Change the magento home page logo.

3.) Change the Top links "name" Ex: My Cart as image.

4.) Adding new link in top links.

```
5.) Move the top menu navigation as left menu navigation.
```

6.) Creating banner slider in home page

7.) Listing the feature products in home page.

8.) Need to put newsletter subscription in footer area.

9.) Removing the magento ads in right column (i.e) The dog and poll removing.

10.) Adding the new column in sort by order in category page.

11.) In product detail page need to show product description and some other information as tab format.

12.) Magento registeration need to enable extra options like company name, phone number, address, user type.

13.) Each customer group need to show different type of price for products.

14.) While importing products we to import the tier price to each products.

15.) Creating new attributes to products. And need to import values to that new attribute.

16.) Adding custom new column while registering a customer. And it need to show in admin side as editable.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are in e-commerce domain and magneto is a e-commerce framework which provide a platform to build e-commerce application with some build in out of the box functionality so that the developer at the end of the day not have to start building things from scratch.

```
what type to tasks we can do in Magneto.
```

being a eCommerce platform it provides you out of the box functionality ranging from product management,category/catalog management,shipping,checkout process,user management,post order process etc  and many other things.

E-commerce in itself start from application like `B2C (Business to customer), B2B (business to business)`.

```
I want some good tricky and sample tasks to do in magento
```

i am not sure what exactly you mean by this statement what you want to learn how exactly flow going on or how you can customize the things.

my suggestion is to explore some e-commerce implementations like amazon,eBay etc see how things flow there and than come out what you want to have in all.

i have not worked with magento but being in e-commerce domain i know every platform provide some sample reference application so it should be the case with Magento so just run that application and see how flow is going on and play around with it.

one thing that seems good to start is checkout process as it is always an integral part of any B2C implementation.
Other aspect is Product content management.

Comment: Sorry typo mistake that is "what type of tasks we can do in Magneto?
" means I need some list of tasks I can to for learning.

Comment: @Alfred:my suggestion is either go to there feature page where they might have written what it offering and best way is to just explore Amazon or eBay they are working on same model what magento is there to offer.Go for checkout process it includes a lot of module of any eCommerce platform.

Answer (score 0):

How about learning to create tier prices for customer options? I am quite sure that you need this for the future someday.
Magento allows tier prices for products and prices for individual options. However, tier prices for individual options are not supported. Tier prices for individual options are needed e.g. when selling promotional items or textiles with custom imprints. To create individual tier prices just try one of these three options:
one of these three options:

1. Realizing the surcharges with Cart Price Rules
2. Simple Configurable Products / Better Configurable Products
3. Generating additional individual options with prices

In my opinion the last one is the best solution. An individual option only allows one surcharge, when more are needed (one for each tier price you want to have). So you create several options with different prices. By doing so the following module might help you. You can request it for free at: http://www.code4business.de/kontakt-impressum/.
This module requires entering of tier prices and individual options in the backend. Afterwards the prices of the individual options for each tier price are entered in the newly generated options. When you save it, the following table of individual options will be generated. In this table, the tier prices can be entered for the original individual options. After filling out all these fields, the result is expected to be in the checkout.
I hope this is the kind of learning-idea you imagined! If you have further questions just take a look at this link. It offers you detailed descriptions with pictures how to create tier prices:
http://www.code4business.de/tier-prices-for-magento-custom-options-en/